# Cross object formula in salesforce

Tags: salesforce

I m new to salesforce. I need ur help. How to create a lookup formula for custom object. How can i insert the field type that is related to my object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't really understand what you need. If you want to create a new lookup field for your object - go to the object, click "New" in custom fields, select "Lookup Relationship" and click "Next", select your related object and that's it. 
In case you want to create a new formula field select "Formula" as "Data Type".